# Twisted - Sending a file hierarchy

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

Basically, I want to get a hierarchy of files on a server and send it to a connected client that has sent a certain command. I have my code written properly so that it's detecting the command and will go where it needs to go in order to generate the hierarchy, but here is where I'm stuck. Is there a way to do this other than sending a bunch of formatted strings (tabs to designate one folder deeper, etc)? I was thinking something like a list and then sending said list via transport.write, but when I do the client doesn't receive it, or at least dataReceived isn't being triggered. I'm at a loss as to what to do. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using, so that we can have some idea why `dataReceived` isn't getting called. If something so basic isn't working, you probably have a pretty basic problem you need to solve. You need to be able to send simple strings before you can start worrying about how to serialize hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a string to the other side. That means you'll need to serialise your hierarchy somehow. Unless you already have some special way of dealing with binary data in your app, I'd suggest just using some standard. Save your hierarchy as [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), [msgpack](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python/), [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial), [thrift](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/thrift), or something else that's already implemented well.

Then just unpack using the same library on the other side.

Comment: This won't work reliably, because first you have to reassemble your strings.  See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith

Comment: It will work reliably, you just have to reassemble your strings ;)